# IBM Integration Bus v10 Flow Exercisor MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2495'

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

When i try to test my very simple message flow I get this error:

> MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2495'.

I've seen the other questions related to this problem, but none solution helped me solve this...

This sentence:

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: mqjbnd (Not found in java.library.path)

suggest that there is missing libmqjbnd.so or there is no path in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but I already check this [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21413508) and follow instructions...

My LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

`/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/common/jdk/jre/lib/amd64:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/common/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/classic:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/ie02/lib:/var/mqsi/extensions/10.0.0/server/lib:/var/mqsi/extensions/10.0.0/lib:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/server/xml4c/lib:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/server/lib:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/server/bin:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/server/ODBC/drivers/lib:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/server/xlxpc/lib:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/server/dfdlc/lib:/opt/mqm/java/lib64/libmqjbnd.so`

And ldd on libmqjbnd.so:

`root@Lenovo-PB01BPG9:/opt/mqm/java/lib64# ldd libmqjbnd.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd05757000)
    libmqe_r.so => /opt/mqm/lib64/libmqe_r.so (0x00007fbfdd615000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbfdd3de000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fbfdd1da000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbfdce14000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fbfdcb0e000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fbfdc906000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fbfdc601000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005603277f4000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fbfdc3eb000)`

I've also tried to just deploy this app and put message on queue, but the MQInput node doesn't get any message, even in failure output (transition) and MQExplorer shows 1 message in queue.

Here is the msg flow:
[image]

I'm using local integration node and local queue manager.

**What am I missing?**

More variables..

$MQ_JAVA_LIB_PATH:

`/opt/mqm/java/lib64`

$MQ_JAVA_DATA_PATH:

`/var/mqm`

$MQ_JAVA_INSTALL_PATH:

`/opt/mqm/java`

$CLASSPATH:

`/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/server/messages:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/common/classes:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/server/classes:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/common/jackson/lib/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.6.3.jar:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/common/jackson/lib/jackson-core-2.6.3.jar:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/common/jackson/lib/jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/common/jackson/lib/jackson-annotations-2.6.3.jar:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/common/jetty/lib/websocket-common.jar:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/common/jetty/lib/websocket-client.jar:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/common/jetty/lib/websocket-api.jar:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/common/jetty/lib/jetty-http.jar:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/common/jetty/lib/jetty-client.jar:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/common/jetty/lib/jetty-util.jar:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/common/jetty/lib/jetty-io.jar:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/common/classes/IntegrationAPI.jar:/opt/IIB/iib-10.0.0.6/server/classes/brokerutil.jar:/var/mqsi/common/wsrr:/opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mq.jar:/opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mqjms.jar:/opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar:/opt/mqm/samp/wmqjava/samples:/opt/mqm/samp/jms/samples`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>
> :/opt/mqm/java/lib64/libmqjbnd.so

You only need the path and not path & filename.

Secondly, dump out the 'java.library.path' JVM environment variable at the start of your program:

```
System.out.println("java.library.path="+java.library.path);
```

Comment: Thank you! Adding /opt/mqm/java/lib64/ without filename resolve my problem.